# Extract data from Crystal Reports via Web Service

Tags: web-services, rest, crystal-reports, export-to-csv, business-objects

I would like to access the aggregated data of a chart in a Crystal Report. It seems there are many different Web services such as SAP BO RESTful Web Service, Crystal Reports REST WebService, OpenDocument Web service and it is - to be honest - a bit confusing.

Does anyone know if accessing the aggregated data of a Crystal Report via a Web Service is possible?
If so, which web service is the correct one?
In the best case I would expect to get the data in XML or JSON format in return.

Thanks for your suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Crystal Reports, but you can already eliminate OpenDocument for this scenario, as this is used to open a document hosted in the BI Platform, and display it in the browser. The use case for OpenDocument is to provide inter- and intra-document links as well as allow you to link from outside the BI Platform to a specific document.

Using the Crystal Report REST SDK, you could perhaps use the OData protocol to retrieve the necessary information. Have a look at the [RESTful Web Services documentation](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41_cr_restful_ws_en.pdf) to see if that provides what you need (OData is described in section 3.6).